# PHP sessions don't work in Android?

Tags: php, android, session

I have an issue with my Android app and my php files.

I have two php files: 
* the first one is connecting after a long if/else  blocks:

```
[...]
else{

                $response["message"]="Connexion OK";

                session_start();
                $_SESSION['id'] = $id;
                $_SESSION['pseudo'] = $pseudo;
                $_SESSION['options'] = $options;
                $response['session'] = $_SESSION['id'];
            }
[...]
echo json_encode($response);
```

My second file only return if connected or not:

```
<?php

session_start();
$response =0;

    if(isset($_SESSION['id'])){
        $response= 1;
    }



echo $response;
```

?>

When I execute URL of files in Firefox, in this order:
1/ the second one, I have 0
2/ The fist one
3/ The second one again, I get 1

The Php files are well construct!

Now, I want to do this in AsyncTasks Android: wherever the activity in which I am, the first thing I want to test the user connexion with the second file: but the return is always 0...not connected, even after i have been logged with the first one which is called in an Connexion Activity.

Is there something moreover in Android to open Php sessions?

Thanks for answers,

---

Here is my code:
I have an AsyncTask for connexion:

```
private class AddDataAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
        String message = "";
        [...] //preExecute
        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {


            Log.i("add", " start doInBackground");

            // Making a request to url and getting response

            String urlt = url;
            if (nameValuePair != null) {
                String paramString = URLEncodedUtils.format(nameValuePair, "utf-8");

            }
            String response = "";
            try {

                DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();

                CookieStore cookieStore = new BasicCookieStore();
                                    HttpContext localContext = new BasicHttpContext();
                                    localContext.setAttribute(ClientContext.COOKIE_STORE, cookieStore);

                HttpGet post = new HttpGet(urlt);
                HttpResponse rp = httpClient.execute(post);
                if (rp.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() != HttpStatus.SC_OK) {
                    // Server is unavailable
                }
                response = EntityUtils.toString(rp.getEntity()); //here is your response

            } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
           /* } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            */
            if (response != null) {
                try {

                    JSONObject JsonResponse = new JSONObject(response);
                    message = JsonResponse.getString("message");

                    if (message.equals("Connexion OK"))
                        session = Integer.parseInt(JsonResponse.getString("session"));
                        Log.i("connnnnnexionC", response);
                } catch (JSONException e) {

                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            return null;
```

[...] //postExecute
            }

And my AsyncTask where I want to check connexion:

```
        private class VerifierConnexionAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
                [...] //preExecute

                @Override
                protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

                    String response = "";
                    try {

                        DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                        HttpEntity httpEntity = null;
                        HttpResponse httpResponse = null;


                        CookieStore cookieStore = new BasicCookieStore();
                        HttpContext localContext = new BasicHttpContext();
                        localContext.setAttribute(ClientContext.COOKIE_STORE, cookieStore);

                        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
                        httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
                        httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
                        response = EntityUtils.toString(httpEntity);
                        Log.i("connnnnexion",response);
                    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                    return null;
                }

    [...]//postExecute
            }
```

First I enter the check the result is:

I/connnnnexion﹕ 0

I go to the Connexion Activity and I logged using the first AsyncTask: I got:

I/connnnnnexionC﹕ {"message":"Connexion OK","session":"27"}

So it well connect

I reenter the check, and again I have:

I/connnnnexion﹕ 0

---

**SOLUTION**
I've written a new Class Connecte:

```
    import org.apache.http.client.CookieStore;
import org.apache.http.client.protocol.ClientContext;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.BasicCookieStore;
import org.apache.http.protocol.BasicHttpContext;
import org.apache.http.protocol.HttpContext;
public class Connecte {
    static CookieStore cookieStore;
    static HttpContext localContext;

    public static void makeCookie(){
        cookieStore = new BasicCookieStore();
        localContext = new BasicHttpContext();
        localContext.setAttribute(ClientContext.COOKIE_STORE, cookieStore);
    }


}
```

In connexion AsyncTask I add: Connexion.makeCookie():

```
HttpGet post = new HttpGet(urlt);
                Connecte.makeCookie();
                HttpResponse rp = httpClient.execute(post, Connecte.localContext);
```

And in the check asynctask I just add:

```
HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
                httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost, Connecte.localContext);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to make sure that the connection you are using is reusing the same cookies. PHP manages sessions by given each client a PHP_SESSION cookie and keeps track of various values based on your PHP_SESSION. If you don't keep track of that between each request then php will think you're a different client each time.

`CookieHandler.setDefault( new CookieManager( null, CookiePolicy.ACCEPT_ALL ) );`

---

```
DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpEntity httpEntity = null;
HttpResponse httpResponse = null;

CookieStore cookieStore = new BasicCookieStore();
HttpContext localContext = new BasicHttpContext();
localContext.setAttribute(ClientContext.COOKIE_STORE, cookieStore);

HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);

httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost, localContext);
httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
```

Make sure to reuse the same localContext object in all future requests so they all share the same cookies and can persist PHP sessions.

Comment: @ImFabien75 if this helped you, please accept/upvote it.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Before upvoting it, just to be sure: I write:CookieHandler.setDefault( new CookieManager( null, CookiePolicy.ACCEPT_ALL ) );  in each activity, when I want to test the Connexion, before opening php file?

Comment: @ImFabien75 you write what? Your comment got cut off

Comment: Oh sorry, i edited it but it didn't work!! I was wondering how and where to use it: In my Android code, I have a lot of calls to php files like this: DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                    HttpEntity httpEntity = null;
                    HttpResponse httpResponse = null;
                    HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
                    httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
                    httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
                    response = EntityUtils.toString(httpEntity);

Comment: Do I use it before that, or just once after the opening of the session after connexion?

Comment: @ImFabien75 1) please refrain from posting multiline code snippets in a comment. You can just edit your post. 2) CookieHandler is if you were using HttpUrlConnection. Since you didn't post anything useful in determining how you were doing connections from android in your post I had to assume you were doing it that way. 3) i am editing my answer with how to use a CookieStore for you.

Comment: @ImFabien75 did this help?

Comment: Hello, I've just tried...and that's don't work...I am editing my first post with my programming, so you'll be able to have a better understanding maybe!  :)

Comment: @ImFabien75 so you did it wrong. What you need to do is declare a localContext and cookiestore that's not going to get reinstantiated every network request. It has to be one object in memory that's shared between the requests otherwise you'll not be able to keep the session. Try doing that

Comment: Great thank you! It works! :D I will edit first post to write my solution! I've upvoted yours!